# Unzip files within the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to unzip some files. I can do it with xp_cmdshell using 7z (since it is free) but I need this procedure to be able to run on multiple machined and I cannot guarantee that all of them will have 7z. Can I include the installation of 7z into the SQL Server?

Comment: Why not use powershell or ssis to do OS related tasks as opposed to SQL Server doing it ?

Comment: @Kin Generally so far we have some troubles with windows scheduler and we are trying not to use it as much as possible. On the other hand SQL Agents is way more reliable.

Comment: Agent can run PowerShell.  PowerShell V5+ can unzip. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you very much! This was the answer I was looking for! I did not know I could use PowerShell as SQL Job.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, running compression/decompression on the SQL Server itself is a bad idea.

SQL Server is licensed by the CPU core, so it's the most expensive place in the shop to do CPU-intensive things like compression & decompression. Instead, consider offloading that to an application server.

Now, having said that: SQL Server doesn't support the installation of programs and doesn't have a way to bundle 3rd party apps with the install. You'll want to manage the installation of other apps with a software deployment product or an installer script.